# Check if array of objects key is empty and splice it

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of objects, in that there is an empty key with `Boolean` value, if the `Boolean` value is `false` then the array of objects should be spliced.

The below is the array structure:

```js
this.dataTobeDeleted= [{
    NotificationID: "2180",
    Quantity: 1,
    NotificationName: "453",
    AlertNumber: "02/19/2020",
    "": true
  },
  {
    NotificationID: "2182",
    Quantity: 1,
    NotificationName: "453",
    AlertNumber: "02/19/2020",
    "": false
  },
  {
    NotificationID: "2181",
    Quantity: 1,
    NotificationName: "453",
    AlertNumber: "02/19/2020",
    "": false
  }
]
```

In the above array there is an empty string "key" if the key value is `false` then need to splice the array of objects using index.

Below is the code which I have tried:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < this.dataTobeDeleted.length; i++) {
    for (var val in this.dataTobeDeleted[i]) {
      if (val === "") {

        this.dataTobeDeleted[i]['isCheckedValue'] = this.dataTobeDeleted[i][""]; // insetring new key for empty key string
        delete this.dataTobeDeleted[i][""]; // Delete old key 
        if (this.dataTobeDeleted[i].isCheckedValue === false) {
          this.dataTobeDeleted.splice(i, 1)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The above code is correct, but I need it in shorter way as the code I tried is in lengthier and when there is too much data it will create a problem.

I tried using filter also, but I am not getting the empty key to check the `boolean` value.

Answer (score 3):

Use an array filter to remove the items you don't want:

```
this.dataTobeDeleted.filter(x => !!x[''])
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-template-1t2xz7

This will create a new array, keeping only those where the property `''` is truthy. If you wanted to be stricter, you could use a strict boolean check:

```
this.dataTobeDeleted.filter(x => x[''] === true)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your wanting to do this by mutating the original array using splice.

Make sure you loop the array backwards, this prevents issues of the loop index going out of sync as you mutate the array.

Example below..

```js
const dataTobeDeleted= [{
    NotificationID: "2180",
    Quantity: 1,
    NotificationName: "453",
    AlertNumber: "02/19/2020",
    "": true
  },
  {
    NotificationID: "2182",
    Quantity: 1,
    NotificationName: "453",
    AlertNumber: "02/19/2020",
    "": false
  },
  {
    NotificationID: "2181",
    Quantity: 1,
    NotificationName: "453",
    AlertNumber: "02/19/2020",
    "": false
  }
];

for (let ix = dataTobeDeleted.length -1; ix >= 0; ix --) {
  if (!dataTobeDeleted[ix][''])
    dataTobeDeleted.splice(ix, 1);
}

console.log(dataTobeDeleted);
```

Answer (score 3):

It works for me, please try it

```
var newArr = dataTobeDeleted.filter((val) =>{return val[""] === true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [MDN on `Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, iterated in the same order that a normal loop would.

Then you can find the empty key and remove it with the `delete` method.

```
const deletedData = dataTobeDeleted.map((item, index) => {
    Object.keys(item).map(key => {
        if (!item['']) {
            dataTobeDeleted.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this function removes only key ans value but i want to delete whole object in the array if  the empty key is false

Comment: Unfortunately your update has made this even worse, if you run your code on the OP's data it will look like it's worked.  But if say you add another item set to true it will delete that too.  In fact it will delete the next 4 regardless of the state.

Answer (score 0):

```
const isCheckedValue = obj => !!(obj[''])
this.dataToBeDeleted = dataToBeDeleted.filter(isCheckedValue)
console.log(result)
```

If you want to fix such objects simply use map

```
this.dataToBeDeleted = dataToBeDeleted.map(obj => {
   obj.isCheckedValue = obj['']
   delete obj[''] // mutations, not good :(
})
```

Comment: `mutations, not good :(`  Don't believe the hype.  It really depends.

Answer (score 0):

This is experimental, but you could also dabble with native ES6 iterator (using a generator) instead of looping through the data backwards.

```js
class ClassicIterator {
  constructor(list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.index = 0;
  }
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    while (this.index < this.list.length) {
      yield this.list[this.index];
      this.index++; // Move forward
    }
  }
  remove() {
    this.list.splice(this.index, 1);
    this.index--; // Rollback
  }
}

class InPlaceFilter {
  constructor(opts) {
    this.list = opts.list;
    this.filterFn = opts.filterFn;
  }  
  execute() {
    let it = new ClassicIterator(this.list);
    for (let item of it) {
      if (!this.filterFn(item)) {
        it.remove();
      }
    }
    return this;
  }
  get() {
    return this.list;
  }
}

const data = [
  { NotificationID:"2180", Quantity:1, NotificationName:"453", AlertNumber:"02/19/2020", "":true  },
  { NotificationID:"2181", Quantity:1, NotificationName:"453", AlertNumber:"02/19/2020", "":false },
  { NotificationID:"2182", Quantity:1, NotificationName:"453", AlertNumber:"02/19/2020", "":false },
  { NotificationID:"2183", Quantity:1, NotificationName:"453", AlertNumber:"02/19/2020", "":true  }
];

let sameRef = new InPlaceFilter({
  list : data,
  filterFn : (e) => e[''] === false
}).execute().get();

console.log('Are the same?:', sameRef === data); // Same list!
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Simplified version:

```js
const InPlaceFilter = (opts) => {
  for (let i = opts.list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!opts.filterFn(opts.list[i])) {
      opts.list.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return opts.list;
}

const data = [
  { NotificationID:"2180", Quantity:1, NotificationName:"453", AlertNumber:"02/19/2020", "":true  },
  { NotificationID:"2181", Quantity:1, NotificationName:"453", AlertNumber:"02/19/2020", "":false },
  { NotificationID:"2182", Quantity:1, NotificationName:"453", AlertNumber:"02/19/2020", "":false },
  { NotificationID:"2183", Quantity:1, NotificationName:"453", AlertNumber:"02/19/2020", "":true  }
];

let otherRef = data.filter(e => e[''] === false);
let sameRef = InPlaceFilter({
  list : data,
  filterFn : (e) => e[''] === false
});

console.log('Are the same?:', sameRef === data);     // Same list!
console.log('Are the same?:', sameRef === otherRef); // Not the same list!
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```